# Should redirecting URLs be included or excluded from the XML sitemap?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, sitemap, 302-redirect

Currently, we're working on optimizing a website for search engines. Would you advise adding to the XML sitemap the URLs of the pages that are being redirected, or the redirect target URLs?

In my opinion, I should exclude the redirects, but I don't know what the best practice is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the redirected URLs. Having too many duplicate urls/content is not good.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.   While I believe that your advice is correct, you should explain why.   Either link to articles and documentation; or explain what experience you have that leads you to conclude that.

Comment: It isn't to late to edit this answer now.